# Python- Indexerror: list index out of range while defining a function

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, index-error, data-preprocessing

I am getting the following error when I'm running a python script which is used for pre processing csv file. The error and the code snippet is shown below. In the function get_mech_update(), the arguments have the following types:

- slat_tr - list
- flap_tr - list
- template- csv file with certain rows and columns

The error is on the line with the code :

- template=template.append([template]*(len(slat_tr)+len(flap_tr))*2,ignore_index=True)

pics 1 and 2 combined is the **overall code of function** get_mech_update()

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXRIr.png)

[1)The code snippet from the function def](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tOr5.jpg)

[2)Contd. code snippet from the function def](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmrtZ.jpg)

In the function call the three arguments have following types and sizes:

```
slat_tr -> null list->[]
flap_tr -> null list->[]
template-> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame-> 642 rows and 15 columns
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow. By any chance `slat_tr` or `flap_tr` can be empty lists? If yes then the list of templates you are passing in `append` function will be empty and causing an Index Error where pandas is trying to extract an item from the provided list. You can also write your code here only in code blocks instead of pasting image links. That'll be readable.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)